# change file open mode with a kernel module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, fedora, redhat

I'm doing some test with a kernel module for change a file open mode of a process from write to readonly with the following code, I take the file descriptor number from `lsof -p <pid of process>` and compile the module && insmod changefilemode.ko it works on fedora 19, but if Ido it on RedHat 5, the file descriptor is closed.

```
  #include <linux/kernel.h>
  #include <linux/module.h>
  #include <linux/init.h>
  #include <linux/sched.h>
  #include <linux/file.h>
  #include <linux/fs.h>


  struct files_struct *get_files_struct(struct task_struct *task)
  {
       struct files_struct *files;

       task_lock(task);
       files = task->files;
       if (files)
              atomic_inc(&files->count);
       task_unlock(task);

       return files;
   }


   MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

   static int __init myinit(){
         struct task_struct *tsk;
         for_each_process(tsk){

         if(tsk->pid == 11923){
                    struct files_struct *files = get_files_struct(tsk);
                    task_lock(tsk);
                    printk("\tpid %d - file mode %d\n",tsk->pid, files->fd_array[6]->f_mode);
                    files->fd_array[6]->f_mode = FMODE_READ;
                    printk("\tpid %d - file mode %d\n",tsk->pid, files->fd_array[6]->f_mode);
                    task_unlock(tsk);
               }
         }
      return 0;
   }

static void  __exit myexit(){
    printk("Good Bye from exit");
}


module_init(myinit);
module_exit(myexit);
```

Comment: Seriously? Your kernel module has a hard-coded PID in it? How do you intend to arrange that your test program always has that PID?

Comment: because i used syslog pid, i took the syslog pid and i puted in the module

Comment: What kind of file is it that you're closing? I.e. what is fd 6 in that process?

Comment: when i did the test, fd 6 was /var/log/messages

Comment: You wrote _syslog pid_ - did you mean `syslogd`?

Answer (score 0):

Exact PID values are dependent on the exact chronology of process launch during startup.
There is no way to insure the exact chronology of process launch is deterministic across distributions, unless you are carefully tweaking things to your exact needs, and assuming init process is exactly the same.

Also fd number depends on the chronology of `open()` during process execution.

Comment: yes i know the pid and file the descriptor are not always the same, i recompiled my module everytimes i load it